# Getting Java javafx.fxml.LoadException: in IntelliJ and JavaFX scene builder

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx-2, scenebuilder

This is my main class

```
package FSM;

import java.io.IOException;

import FSM.view.PersonEditDetailsControler;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import FSM.model.Person;
import FSM.view.PersonOverviewController;



public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;
    private ObservableList<Person> personData= FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public Main() {
        // Add some sample data
        System.out.println("1 prit");
        personData.add(new Person("Hans", "Muster"));
        personData.add(new Person("Ruth", "Mueller"));
        personData.add(new Person("Heinz", "Kurz"));
        personData.add(new Person("Cornelia", "Meier"));
        personData.add(new Person("Werner", "Meyer"));
        personData.add(new Person("Lydia", "Kunz"));
        personData.add(new Person("Anna", "Best"));
        personData.add(new Person("Stefan", "Meier"));
        personData.add(new Person("Martin", "Mueller"));
    }
    public ObservableList<Person> getPersonData() {
        return personData;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("2 print");
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");

        initRootLayout();

        showPersonOverview();


    }

    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // Load root layout from fxml file.
                System.out.println("rootLayout");
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                System.out.println("geting rootlayout");
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/FSM/view/RootLayout.fxml"));
                System.out.println("setting borderPane");
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
                System.out.println("loaded");
            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
                System.out.println("new scene 1");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                System.out.println("set scene");
            primaryStage.show();
                System.out.println("rootLayout End 1");
        } catch (IOException e) {

                System.out.println("rootLayout Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void showPersonOverview() {
        try {
            System.out.println("3 Print");
            // Load person overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                System.out.println("getting Resouurce");
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/FSM/view/PersonOverview.fxml"));
                System.out.println("got Resouurce");
            AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
                System.out.println("loading Anchor");
            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);
                System.out.println("setting person overview");
           PersonOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
           controller.setMain(this);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("3 Print exception");
        }
    }

    public boolean showPersonEditDialog(Person person){
        try {
            System.out.println("4 print");
            FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/FSM/view/PersonEditDetails.fxml"));
            AnchorPane anchorPane=(AnchorPane)loader.load();

            rootLayout.setCenter(anchorPane);

            Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
            dialogStage.setTitle("Edit Person");
            dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
            Scene scene = new Scene(anchorPane);
            dialogStage.setScene(scene);


            PersonEditDetailsControler controllerr = loader.getController();
            controllerr.setDialogStage(dialogStage);
            controllerr.setPerson(person);

            dialogStage.showAndWait();

            return controllerr.isOKClicked();

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("4th print");
            return false;

        }
    }

    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And this is PersonOverViewController class

```
package FSM.view;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

import FSM.model.Person;
import FSM.Main;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEvent;

import java.lang.Object.*;


/**
 * Created by mfaseem on 6/9/2015.
 */
public class PersonOverviewController {



    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> PersonTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person,String> fnameColumn;

    @FXML
    private  TableColumn<Person, String> lnameColumn;

    @FXML
    private Label fnameLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label lnameLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label streetLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label postelCodeLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label CityLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label dobLabel;

    private Main main;

    public  PersonOverviewController(){

    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize(){
        fnameColumn.setCellValueFactory(CellData -> CellData.getValue().fnameProperties());
        lnameColumn.setCellValueFactory(CellData -> CellData.getValue().lnameProperties());

        showPersonDetails(null);

        PersonTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) ->showPersonDetails(newValue));
    }

    @FXML
    private void deleteHandler(){
        int selectedIndex=PersonTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

        if(selectedIndex>=0){
            PersonTable.getItems().remove(selectedIndex);
        }else {

        //  ALERT alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
           //alert.initOwner(mainApp.getPrimaryStage());
           // alert.setTitle("No Selection");
           // alert.setHeaderText("No Person Selected");
         //   alert.setContentText("Please select a person in the table.");

          //  alert.showAndWait();
        }


    }


    @FXML
    private void handleNewPerson() {
        Person tempPerson = new Person();
        boolean okClicked = main.showPersonEditDialog(tempPerson);
        if (okClicked) {
            main.getPersonData().add(tempPerson);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleEditPerson() {
        Person selectedPerson = PersonTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (selectedPerson != null) {
            boolean okClicked = main.showPersonEditDialog(selectedPerson);
            if (okClicked) {
                showPersonDetails(selectedPerson);
            }

        } else {
            /* Nothing selected.
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.WARNING);
            alert.initOwner(mainApp.getPrimaryStage());
            alert.setTitle("No Selection");
            alert.setHeaderText("No Person Selected");
            alert.setContentText("Please select a person in the table.");

            alert.showAndWait();
            */
        }
    }

    public void setMain(Main main){
        this.main=main;
        PersonTable.setItems(main.getPersonData());

    }

    private void showPersonDetails(Person person){

        if(person !=null){

            fnameLabel.setText(person.getFname());
            lnameLabel.setText(person.getLname());
            streetLabel.setText(person.getStreet());
            CityLabel.setText(person.getCity());
            dobLabel.setText(person.getBirthDate().toString());
            postelCodeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(person.getPostalCode()));
        }else{

            fnameLabel.setText("");
            lnameLabel.setText("");
            streetLabel.setText("");
            CityLabel.setText("");
            dobLabel.setText("");
            postelCodeLabel.setText("");

        }
    }


}
```

And the out put is

```
Device "Intel(R) Q45/Q43 Express Chipset" (\\.\DISPLAY1) initialization failed : 
WARNING: bad driver version detected, device disabled. Please update your driver to at least version 8.15.10.2302
1 prit
2 print
rootLayout
geting rootlayout
setting borderPane
loaded
new scene 1
set scene

javafx.fxml.LoadException:         /C:/Users/mfaseem/IdeaProjects/AddressApp/out/production/AddressApp/FSM/view/PersonOverview.fxml:7
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:104)
```

Can any one help me thanks in advance

Comment: please any one try thnks

Comment: Can you add the complete stacktrace?

Comment: The problem is in PersonOverview.fxml line 7. You need to post it as well.

Comment: Thank you Very much @Uluk Biy as you mentioned there was a problem in that line even I corrected it it continue with other error

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Thank you very much for you concern and I tried to edit and post the Qn again bt was impossible

Comment: fnameColumn.setCellValueFactory(CellData -> CellData.getValue().fnameProperties());
        lnameColumn.setCellValueFactory(CellData -> CellData.getValue().lnameProperties());
THis is my 57th line which printed in stack trace   
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at FSM.view.PersonOverviewController.initialize(PersonOverviewController.java:57)